# Does rounding violate the restrictions of an interval scale?

Tags: scales, measurement, scale-invariance

I'm currently working with questionnaire data from the [NASA TLX](https://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/). It uses a graphical rating scale with 100 equally spaced data points, broken up by 21 ticks, leaving intervals of 5.
Its [manual (p. 4)](https://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/downloads/TLX_pappen_manual.pdf) advises on rounding *up* responses that lie between the tick marks to the nearest tick (which is a multiple of 5).

My gut tells me that this seems a bad idea (apart from loosing valuable information) because to me it seems like this violates the restriction of linear transformation proposed by [Stevens](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1671815) for the interval scale.

In the paper I'm writing I would like to use the unrounded values and use the interval scale argument but I did not manage to track down an appropriate reference and I wanted to make sure that my thoughts are correct.